# Update Databse if checkbox its checked (Get checkbox without load again)

Tags: javascript, php

So I trying many things...but they didn't work I need to know when checkbox its checked and update database

Code

```
var lfckv = document.getElementById("squaredThree3").checked;
if (lfckv==false)
{
    <?php 
    $exist = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE ip = '$ip'"));
    if((!$exist)){
        mysql_query ("INSERT INTO settings (ip, recentmovies, recentposts, popularmovies, popularposts) VALUES ('$ip','yes','yes','yes','yes')");
    }
        mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET recentmovies='no' WHERE ip = '$ip'");
    ?>
}
```

I know that is not working but this is what I want to do..but to make it work in some way...can anyone help me..

Comment: You can"t execute PHP code simply by putting it in Javascript code.

Comment: I know that...But how can I make it work with another way

Comment: Do you use a `<form>`? Do you want to perform a MySQL query as soon as the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Since you don't want the page to load again you can make an AJAX call to that piece of code that updates the database, whenever the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: @WilliamJanoti I'm no so good at jquery :/

Comment: One way is to put this piece of PHP code in a .php file then call it via AJAX passing weather the checkbox is checked or not as a parameter

Answer (score -1):

Use Ajax:

```
var lfckv = document.getElementById("squaredThree3").checked;
 if (lfckv==false){
  $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
    });
 }
```